# Selects in a form displaying strangely?

Tags: html, asp.net, razor

I have never seen select tags behave this way before until building a web app with ASP.NET.

[image]

They display all of the options available instead of an empty selection that drops down regularly.

edit

```
<div class="form-group">
    <span asp-validation-for="Local"></span>
    <label asp-for="Local"></label>
    <select asp-for="Local" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Local))">
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <span asp-validation-for="Language"></span>
    <label asp-for="Language"></label>
    <select asp-for="Language" class="custom-select" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Language))">
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the razor code you have that renders the drop down lists?

Comment: Looks like a multi select box. Can you select more than one with ctrl?

Comment: yeah, I can make multiple selections.

Comment: the class attributes are setup incorrectly but they did match earlier, and yielded the same result as now. Is the problem from not using option tags?

Answer (score 0):

I had Local and Language properties in my Model typed as Lists which seemed to cause the problem. Taking care of it now.